# Approximating Pi, Monte Carlo integration

Tags: java, random, numerical-methods, akka

I wrote some code that uses [Monte Carlo Integration](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monte_Carlo_integration) to Approximate pi in Java and Akka. The tl;dr explanation is you can imagine throwing darts at a square with a circle inscribed inside of it. You know the area formulas for a square and a circle so you can use the ratio of darts that landed in the circle vs those that landed in the square to reconstruct pi.

## Config.java

```
package populate;

/**
 * Global class used to change world parameters.
 * At the moment, you can only change the number of actors
 * in the world.
 */
public class Config {
    public static int ACTOR_COUNT = 20;
}
```

## Dart.java

```
package populate;

import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dart extends UntypedActor {

    // Location of darts thrown.
    private ArrayList<Point> darts;

    /**
     * Throws a bunch of "darts" at a square.
     * @param size  The number of darts thrown.
     */
    private void throwDarts(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            darts.add(Point.genRandPoint());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use Monte Carlo integration to approximate pi.
     * (see: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monte_Carlo_integration)
     */
    private float approximatePi() {
        int total = 0; // Keep track of total points thrown.
        int inside = 0; // Keep track of points inside the circle.
        for (Point d : darts) {
            if (d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y <= 1) {
                inside += 1;
            }
            total += 1;
        }
        return 4 * ((float) inside) / total;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        if (msg != null) {
            this.throwDarts(50);
            getSender().tell(approximatePi(), getSelf());
        } else {
            getContext().stop(getSelf());
            unhandled(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        darts = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
}
```

## Main.java

```
package populate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        akka.Main.main(new String[] { World.class.getName() });
    }

}
```

## Point.java

```
package populate;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Point {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    static public Point genRandPoint() {
        return new Point(
                ThreadLocalRandom
                .current()
                .nextDouble(-1, 1),
                ThreadLocalRandom
                .current()
                .nextDouble(-1, 1)
              );
    }
}
```

## World.java

```
package populate;

import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;

/**
 * This class is responsible for creating the "dart-throwing" actors.
 * It is also responsible for averaging the results of the Dart actors.
 */
public class World extends UntypedActor {

    // Sum of the Dart Actor results.
    private static double sum = 0.0;
    // Keep track of actors still going.
    private static Integer actorsLeft = Config.ACTOR_COUNT;

    /**
     * Calculate the "average of the averages".
     * Each Dart actor approximates pi. This function takes those results
     * and averages them to get a *hopefully* better approximation of pi.
     */
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        if (msg != null) {
            sum += (Float) msg;
            actorsLeft--;
            if (actorsLeft <= 0) {
                System.out.println(sum / (double) Config.ACTOR_COUNT);
                getContext().stop(getSelf());
            }
        } else {
            unhandled(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a number of darts and tells the Dart actors
     * and tells them to start computing.
     */
    @Override
    public void preStart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Config.ACTOR_COUNT; i++) {
            final ActorRef dart = getContext()
                .actorOf(
                    Props.create(Dart.class), 
                    "dart" + Integer.toString(i));
            // The choice of "0" is used, but anything non-null would
            // work. (If it were null, the Dart actor would die before
            // it did any work.
            dart.tell(0, getSelf());
        }
    }
}
```

The full repo can be [found here](https://github.com/thyrgle/MonteCarlo) and can be run with `gradle run`.

I don't feel very confident with my understanding of Akka...

Comment: Small thing not worth an answer: Don't write a config class: you already have a config file from akka, you can use that instead and access it "for free" through akka utilities

Answer (score 3):

### Naming

The `Dart` class does *not* define darts. It holds a `Collection` of `Point`s called `darts`. It is a `Quiver`. I would rename `Point` as `Dart` however, and it could extends Java's Point class.

`World` encompasses a lot of things. Maybe a more precise name would be better? How about `DartThrowingCompetition`?

### Using Streams

Streams are compact, and high-performance. If you're throwing a lot of darts, they're worth a look.

For example:

```
private void throwDarts(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        darts.add(Point.genRandPoint());
    }
}
```

Can become:

```
private void throwDarts(int size) {
    darts = IntStream.range(0, size).mapToObj(num -> Point::genRandPoint).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

The next bit may be Off-Topic, I got carried away in my thought process :)

But I would even keep `darts` a Stream to perform the rest of the computations. This is so concise that I compiled it in a single method in the following `PiEvaluator` class:

```
public class PiEvaluator {

    /**
     * Throws a bunch of "darts" at a square.
     * @param size  The number of darts thrown.
     * @return the approximation of PI
     */
    private double evaluatePi(int nbDarts) {
        long hitCount = IntStream.range(1, nbDarts)
                                 .mapToObj(num -> TestStream.throwOneDart())
                                 .filter(hit -> hit==true)
                                 .count();
        return 4 * (double) hitCount / nbDarts;
    }

    /**
     * Throws one dart at random. If the dart hits the target, return true.
     * @return true if the dart lands on target
     */
    public boolean throwOneDart(){
        Point dart = Point.genRandPoint();
        return dart.x * dart.x + dart.y * dart.y <= 1;
    }
}
```

However I'm afraid I didn't use the `akka` framework at all (I'm not familiar with it) so this might be off-topic. Knowing Streams are lazy, and will wait for the last meaningful call to do the work, I'm not even sure it's akka-able.